# Keras/TensorFlow: Adding a new metric with an inequality

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use Keras with a TensorFlow backend to build an ANN. After each epoch I would like to store the number of datum that are within x points from the stated answer (currently I'm using 8). I believe the way to do this in Keras/TensorFlow is to build a new metric. I've tried this with this code:

```
import keras.backend as K
def inRange(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sum(K.less_equal(K.abs(y_true-y_pred), 8)) / y_true.shape[0]

# Compile model
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy', inRange])
```

but I keep getting errors, that latest is:

```
TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'input' has DataType bool not in list of allowed values: float32, float64, int64, int32, uint8, uint16, int16, int8, complex64, complex128, qint8, quint8, qint32, float16
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

I'm using Anaconda Python 3.5, Tensorflow 1.1.0 and Keras 2.0.6 in a Windows 10 environment using the Spyder IDE.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`K.less_equal(x, y)`](https://keras.io/backend/#less_equal) returns a `tensor` of `bool` values, and in Tensorflow `bool` is not the same as integers (as we get used to in C-like languages). You need to cast it using [`K.cast(x, dtype)`](https://keras.io/backend/#cast) to either `int32` or `float32` accordingly. In general a Tensor is an algebraic variable, so you cannot treat it as regular arrays. For this reason, you should use [`K.shape(x)`](https://keras.io/backend/#shape) instead of `x.shape`. Try something like this one:

```
def inRange(y_true, y_pred):
    t = K.sum(K.cast(K.less_equal(K.abs(y_true-y_pred), 8.0), 'float32'))
    return t / K.shape(y_true)[0]
```

Please note the working range of floating point numbers or 32bit integers. In some cases, you might want to use `int64` or `float64` instead.

Comment: Thanks. However, this doesn't seem to be working, I'm getting the error `ValueError: Cannot convert an unknown Dimension to a Tensor: ?`

Comment: @jlt199 your new error was caused by `y_true.shape[0]`.